# Swift sign extension with variable number of bits

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

I need to sign-extend an 8bit value to 12 bits. In C, I can do it this way. I read Apple's BinaryInteger protocol documentation, but it didn't explain sign extending to a variable number of bits (and i'm also pretty new at Swift). How can I do this in Swift, assuming val is UInt8 and numbits is 12?

```
#define MASKBITS(numbits) ((1 << numbits) - 1)

#define SIGNEXTEND_TO_16(val, numbits)              \        
(                                                         \
(int16_t)((val & MASKBITS(numbits)) | (                 \
  (val & (1 << (numbits-1))) ? ~MASKBITS(numbits) : 0)  \
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Int8(bitPattern:)` to convert the given unsigned
value to a signed value with the same binary representation, 
then sign extend by converting to `Int16`, make unsigned again, and finally truncate
to the given number of bits:

```
func signExtend(val: UInt8, numBits: Int) -> UInt16 {
    // Sign extend to unsigned 16-bit:
    var extended = UInt16(bitPattern: Int16(Int8(bitPattern: val)))
    // Truncate to given number of bits:
    if numBits < 16 {
        extended = extended & ((1 << numBits) - 1)
    }
    return extended
}
```

Example:

```
for i in 1...16 {
    let x = signExtend(val: 200, numBits: i)
    print(String(format: "%2d %04X", i, x))
}
```

Output:

```
 1 0000
 2 0000
 3 0000
 4 0008
 5 0008
 6 0008
 7 0048
 8 00C8
 9 01C8
10 03C8
11 07C8
12 0FC8
13 1FC8
14 3FC8
15 7FC8
16 FFC8
```

Comment: This works well for 8bit values, many thanks! One more question: How would I sign-extend a 12-bit value to Int16?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question in the context of bitstream parsing. I needed code to parse n bit two's complement values into Int32. Here is my solution that works without any condition:

```
extension UInt32 {
    func signExtension(n: Int) -> Int32 {
        let signed = Int32.init(bitPattern: self << (32 - n))
        let result = signed >> (32 - n)
        return result
    }
}
```

And a unit test function showing how to use that code:

```
func testSignExtension_N_2_3() {
    let unsignedValue: UInt32 = 0b110
    let signedValue: Int32 = unsignedValue.signExtension(n: 3)
    XCTAssertEqual(signedValue, -2)
}
```